# EF doesn't get correct entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a problem with my query. In my table, I have 2 elements with `Active` set true. For testing, I try to select only false elements (list should return 0 elements), but I get 2 elements all the time.

Domain class

```
public Guid OrderStatusId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public bool Active { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
```

SQL Elements

```
OrderStatusId = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "xxx", Active = true, Description = "yyy" 
OrderStatusId = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "zzz", Active = true, Description = "xxx"
```

Entity select

```
public List<SlOrderStat> getDataFromSlOrderStat(string name, bool? activity)
{
    activity = false;

    using (var ctx = new ServisContex(conectionString))
    {
        var list = ctx.SlOrdersStats;               

        if (name != string.Empty)
            list.Where(l => l.Name != name);

        if (activity != null)
            list.Where(l => l.Active == activity);

        return list.ToList();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do

```
var result = list.Where(l => l.Name != name);
```

list.Where(...) does not affect the contents of the list itself.

Comment: When i use that i have Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable to 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet

Comment: oh right, I guess the easiest solution would be to just assign the result to another variable, I'll correct my answer.